# How do I break up my PyGame game into separate files?

Tags: python, pygame, file-management

I am teaching a fortnightly coding class to a group of dozen super bright young enthusiasts. We have already covered OOP and created a text based adventure using OOP.

Now I am planning to teach PyGame and continue using objects, and I am wondering if games could be built in such a way where the code for each object is in a separate file?, this would be really neat and easier to build on.

Well For the code below I tried making separate files for each object. This was only partially successful because the draw method never works quite well, I believe the issue that I cannot have separate files referencing the same pygame screen.

```
import pygame
import random
import time

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0,0,255)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 700
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500
pygame.init()

class Paddle:
    '''Class to keep players location'''
    def __init__(self,x=350, y=480, width =70,height=20):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.score = 0

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.change_x
        self.y += self.change_y

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, [self.x,self.y, self.width, self.height])

    def check_collision(self,ball):
        if ball.y>460:
            if abs(35+ self.x - ball.x) < 30:
                self.score += 1
                ball.draw(BLUE)
                ball.y = 0
                ball.x = random.randint(0,650)
                ball.change_y = random.randint(2,3+int(self.score/5))

class Ball:
    """Class to keep track of a ball's location and vector."""
    def __init__(self,x=350,y=250,size=25):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.size = size

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.change_x
        self.y += self.change_y

    def draw(self,colour = WHITE):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE, [self.x, self.y], self.size)


# Set the height and width of the screen
size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Bouncing Balls")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen.fill(BLACK)
ball = Ball()
player = Paddle()
ball.change_y = 2
ball.draw()

while not done:
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    # --- Event Processing
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.change_x = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.change_x = 5
        else:
            ball.change_x = 0
            player.change_x = 0

    if ball.y > 500:
        print('YOUR SCORE: ',player.score)
        time.sleep(2)
        pygame.quit()
    #move ball and player and check if they collide
    ball.move()
    player.move()
    player.check_collision(ball)
    #draw ball and player
    ball.draw()
    player.draw()

    #render frame
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

# Print score and exit
print('YOUR SCORE: ',player.score)
pygame.quit()
```

When I had separate files this is the error that I got in relation to screen

> ```
> line 20, in draw
>    pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE, [self.x, self.y], self.size)
> NameError: name 'screen' is not defined
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `surface` argument to the `draw()` methods of the classes `Paddle` and `Ball` and draw the object on the surface which is passed to the method:

```py
class Paddle:
    # [...]

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, BLUE, [self.x,self.y, self.width, self.height])
```

```py
class Ball:
    # [...]

    def draw(self, surface, colour = WHITE):
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, colour, [self.x, self.y], self.size)
```

Now you can draw the objects on any [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) you want, e.g. `screen`:

```py
ball.draw(screen)
player.draw(screen)
```